# Find / Replace within a String for Windows Forms and Visual Basic .NET -

Tags: vb.net, winforms, string, replace

I have an issue with finding a specific text within a string and then replacing it with " ", which is just a blank entry.

```
Dim ABCTEST As String
ABCTEST = previousJob.Comments.ToString() + currentJob.Comments.ToString()
```

So now my issue is to search the ABCTEST text and delete text such as "Tier Market" from it. Then pass it to a new string perhaps ABCTEST_NEW.

I know I might have to use a `for` loop to search out the keywords, but all the examples I have had a look at, are very broad.

Comment: Use of "&" is recommended over "+" for string concatenation in VB.NET (it is different in C#).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ABCTEST_NEW = ABCTEST.Replace("Tier Market", " ")
```

**String.Replace** method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx